# How do you access a parameter when creating a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, boolean, helper

Meaning that, in PostsController, def create, I want to access the value that is passed in the column for the boolean value agree. When creating a post, there is a checkbox that sets this value. Checked makes agree true (1) and unchecked makes agree false (0). Right now I have the code `params[:post][:agree]` in order to access this value, but that doesn't seem to work.
When I try to use that in an if statement, the statement always occurs, as if params[:post][:agree] always evaluates to true.

Help! Why doesn't this work??

***:EDIT:***

Post.rb (Post Model)

```
 attr_accessor :agree
 attr_accessible :agree
```

PostController (In def create)

```
@post.title = "AGREED!!" if params[:post][:agree] == "1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, neither the number `0` nor the string `"0"` evaluates to `false` in a boolean context. Try `if (params[:post][:agree]=="1")`

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the database column type, then boolean is better. That way your model will work as you expect; IIRC Rails should convert the parameter when you initialize your model.

Comment: Perhaps you should include some more of your code in the question, I'm having a hard time visualizing what it looks like. Can you provide the relevant parts of the model and controller (and maybe the relevant part of the db migration/schema as well)?

Answer (score 1):

Rails, by default creates both a checkbox (with `value="1"`) and a hidden input element (with `value="0"`), so you always get a value passed back to the server, which personally I think is silly and override it.  Try checking if `params[:post][:agree].blank?` instead.

I'm not entirely sure I understand your entire question though.  Were you only talking about the form data, or are you talking about your models?